# Matplotlib interactive figure doesn't show up when display is scaled 150%

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib

I was running some very simple plotting code and noticed that the interactive figures would not show up even though the icon was present on my task bar. I have a 1920x1080 laptop connected to two 4k external monitors and noticed that if I ran the code while the vs-code window was dragged to one of the 4k monitors then no interactive figure window would show up. Running the code while the vs-code window was in my laptop display works fine!

I assumed that this might be due to the figsize parameter in the plt.subplots() function was set too large and I tried lowering it and this seemed to work. I also tried playing around with the windows scaling option in the display settings and saw that once I set the scaling down from 150% to 100% that the figure window started popping up again.

In this first screenshot, you can see that I have my display scaling on each of my 4k monitors set to 150% (the features on the screen are too small to see at 100% scaling).

[Windows scaling 150%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkuKw.png)

But when I try to run this very simple 3-line plotting test code, no interactive window pops up with the plots. The icon appears on my task bar below and when I hover over it I just see a blank window. Here you can also see the 3 lines of code that I am running.

[Blank figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tuEH.png)

Now if I set my display scaling on my 4k monitors to 100%

[Windows scaling 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKboR.png)

Then I get that the interactive plot window nice pops up with the expected plot.

[Good figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LACbW.png)

I couldn't find any information on this while searching and I wonder if it is possible to return to a scaling of 150% while keeping the figsize=(20, 20). Or do I simply need to reduce my figsize values? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are making a 20"x20" figure and then scaling it up to 30"x30".  Most backends will not allow you to create a figure off the screen

Comment: I scaled down to using a figsize = (10, 10) and this results in the same problem. It looks like using a figsize = (10, 8) works though. I guess I will have to use this figsize going forward.